# Convert while read line to awk

Tags: linux, bash, awk, while-loop

While read line is very slow when you are working working with large files. The general suggestion I find from google is to use awk, but how can I convert the following `while` to `awk`?

```
        while read r; do
            html[$dId]+=$(echo -e "\n$r")
            stopList $(echo -e "$r" | tr -d ' ') all
        done <<< "$list"
```

what I've tried

```
        awk '{ 
            html[$dId]+=$(echo -e "\n$0")
            stopList $(echo -e "$0" | tr -d ' ') all
        }' <<< "$list"
```

Comment: some input-data as well as expected output would be nice

Comment: it's a bash function. it's quite big so in order to not confuse i did't include it.

Comment: while read loops over the file line-by-line, same thing as awk does. How large is a large file? And the "magic" parameters, $r, $dId, stopList, what are those?

Comment: what does `stopList` do? to convert this loop to `awk`, we need to perform what it does within the same `awk` process, otherwise there won't be a speed improvement.

Comment: You shouldn't use `awk` to fill in a bash array. Moreover, you shouldn't use bash sub-shell in awk only to use `echo`... And most importantly, you should explain us what's your real need and then we will be able to help you to find a better solution with `awk` avoiding calling several programs for one thing.

Comment: And doing `echo -e` anywhere here is almost certainly redundant and slow, please provide at least an example of sample i/o.

Comment: awk is not shell, awk is a tool which can be called from shell to parse text files. Not sure how awk fits into whatever it is your shell script is doing. If you give us more information with sample input and expected output we could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it's slow is because it's running multiple processes per iteration:

```
while read r; do
    html[$dId]+=$(echo -e "\n$r")
    stopList $(echo -e "$r" | tr -d ' ') all
done <<< "$list"
```

There are: 2 echos, a `tr`, and the `stopList` function, which we don't even know what it does.

To convert this to `awk` you need to rethink a bit, something like this:

```
html[$dId]=$(awk '{ printf("\n%s", $0) }' <<< "$list")
```

That is, instead of appending to `html` line by line, `awk` should generate the whole thing. Inside a single `awk` process you can do very powerful text processing, which will be much more efficient than several `echo`s, `tr`s and such and such in the shell.

My example doesn't include `stopList`, because you didn't explain what it does. Whatever it does, you need to implement it within `awk`, so that it can run within the same `awk` process. Then your script will be much much faster then the current line-by-line `while` loop.